# Row-column scanning to control an 8x8 LED matrix

Tags: arduino-uno, led-matrix

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/RowColumnScanning

This code really confused me because I don't know if the `pixels[x][y]` is HIGH or LOW in `void refreshScreen()`.

As you look at the code, `pixels[x][y]` is HIGH and then LOW in `void setup()`, and then `pixels[x][y]` is HIGH again in `void loop()`. Could anyone explain this to me, please？

Answer (score 2):

The pixels array in initialized to all HIGH in `setup()`. Then one element of the pixel array is set to LOW in `readSensors()`  which turns on one LED.

The tricky bit is you have to remember to turn off the previous LED. That is why in `readSensors()` there is the line where an element of pixels is set HIGH while the pixels' array pointers are still pointing at the former (already lit) LED.